# Better mouse controls with touch screen?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, touchscreen, ubuntu, mouse

I'm using the raspberry pi official 7" touch screen (The one supplied with this http://a.co/gOTsWDC I don't know which model that is) and a raspberry pi 3 model B.

I've noticed two major problems, which are 1) menus close immediately after letting my finger up 2) no way to right click.

Regarding the first issue, in raspian, you can tap and hold and drag your finger to the wanted menu item, which is then selected when you release it. In ubuntu mate (which is what I prefer), tapping and dragging to another menu item has no effect. The menu just hangs open until you release your finger, at which point it simply closes without changing the selected item. Clicking and dragging with an external mouse, however, selects the item as you'd expect.

In both cases, clicking with an external mouse leaves the menu open even after releasing the mouse.

Is there some way to make the touch controls more usable by itself without the use of an external mouse?

Comment: If you willing to try a different OS, that's better designed for touchscreens, that would be an option. If you only want a touchscreen to do specific things (that you could program) you could create a GUI with Tkinter.